# xCode4 Trying to add custom icons to tableView Cells

Tags: xcode4, icons, tableview

I am having mixed results adding custom icons to a tableView. I sure could use some help as to why..

My code is as follows:

```
if (cell.textLabel.text == @"People") {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"People.png"];
    }
    if (cell.textLabel.text == @"Summary") {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Summary.png"];
    }
    if (cell.textLabel.text == @"Date") {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Date.png"];
```

People.png works ok. Summary.png is offset to the right, and Date.png doesn't show.

Please see the attached image..

[image: Custom Cell Sample]

[image: File Inspector]

Comment: Could you modify your original question to include a screenshot of the Project Inspector (the list of files) showing these three png files in your project? Maybe also show the cellForRowAtIndexPath method where your original code lives at.

Comment: Hi Michael, I've added a screenshot of the Project Inspector. I am using Sensible Cocoa*** which has routines that allow me to avoid cellForRowAtIndexPath. Instead, there is a method called willConfigureCell... forRowAtIndexPath. The snippet above is from that method. I am wondering if this is somehow caused as the People cell is a UITextField, while the date is a UIDateField, and the Summary is a UITextView field?

Comment: @mifki's answer is a very very good one (and I wish I had thought of it too). Use `isEqualToString` and see if that fixes your problem. There is no such thing as a `UIDateField`, by the way. What is that field, really?

Comment: Apologies. I should not be writing messages at 4am.. Date is a date field in a core data class entity. Using SensibleCocoa, I do not have to specify the type of field, it picks that up from the core data model. Will test isEqualToString now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing NSStrings with == !?

Comment: NSStrings are compared with `[cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString: @"People"]`

Comment: Brilliant. That helped solve the problem. However, I still have images offset for "Summary". Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Don't know. Are all images of the same size? Maybe some issue with resizing views inside cell..

Comment: Hi, yep, images are the same size. I've contacted the Sensible Cocoa developer, and perhaps he can explain this. I appreciate your help earlier and marked the question as answered.